# SQL CLR project in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sqlclr

After installing the release version of VS2012, I am unable to find SQL CLR proect template.
How can I go about creating a project of this type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

All of the various database objects are now created inside of SQL Server database projects.

They've removed the distinction between database projects (SQL Scripts) and SQL CLR projects.

So it's just `File -> New -> Project`, `Installed -> Templates -> SQL Server`, `SQL Server Database Project`.

Then, if you go to `Add -> New Item`, you'll find various categories on the left, including (confusingly) `SQL CLR` and `SQL CLR C#`. The first is for generating SQL Scripts for adding CLR objects, the second is for creating the actual CLR objects themselves.

Comment: "So it's just File -> New -> Project, Installed -> **Templates** -> **SQL Server**, SQL Server Database Project." Only problem is that I don`t have SQL server under templates. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @Joakim: you must install Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools if you don't have the templates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)

Comment: For me: File -> New Project -> Installed -> Templates -> **Other Languages** -> SQL Server

Comment: I seem to have the 'sql clr' and 'sql clr vb' templates available in ssdt 2010 and ssdt 2012. I'm open to suggestions on how to get 'sql clr c#' added. Causes or solutions?

Comment: Upped for being applicable to VS 2013.