# Cannot open CLR project (created in Visual Studio 2008) in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clr, project

I'm getting this message:

> C:\tfs\cloud\Acision\Acision.DatabaseClr.DocumentService\Acision.DatabaseClr.DocumentService\Acision.DatabaseClr.DocumentService.csproj : error  : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.DatabaseFileNode' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.Internal.FolderNode'.

And in the solution under the project it says:

> The project requires user input. Reload the project for more information.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What steps have you taken to open the project?

Comment: Basically, I switched to VS 2012 last month. Before, I developed this CLR project in VS 2010 and I published it to our DB.

I opened the .sln (done in VS 2010) in VS 2012.

Comment: Check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038952/sql-clr-project-in-vs2012